# command to identify a specific physical disk in a server with many disks

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I have a server containing 10 hard disks. Device `/dev/sdh` is reporting uncorrectable read errors on btrfs scrub. How can I determine which physical disk corresponds to  `/dev/sdh`?

I know I can get the disks' model numbers and serial numbers with `hdparm -I /dev/sd?` and I can get mountpoints with `findmnt` or `lsblk`. However, I am not finding a way to connect `/dev/sdh` to a hard disk by serial number, which is what I need.

Comment: Are UUIDs not sufficient? Have you tried using labels?

Comment: If you have written at least a couple of last digits of serial number of each drive in visible location so that you can check the serial number without removing any drives, matching serial numbers is definitely the way to go. However, this often requires prior planning because the manufacturer printed serial number is often in location that cannot be read while the drive is in active use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lsblk` is one way to do this:

```
lsblk -a -o name,model,size,serial
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
NAME         MODEL             SIZE SERIAL
sdh          ST8000DM002-1YW1  7.3T ZA11A1W3
```

Answer (score 11):

#### lsscsi

On servers where I have a lot of HDDs I've traditionally used `lsscsi` to determine which HDD is plugged into which port.

You can use this output to get the names + the device & generic device names:

```
$ lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDT72101 A3AA  /dev/sda   /dev/sg0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDS72101 A39C  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg1
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Maxtor 6L200P0   1G20  /dev/sdc   /dev/sg2
[12:0:0:0]   disk    WD       My Passport 25E2 4005  /dev/sde   /dev/sg5
[12:0:0:1]   enclosu WD       SES Device       4005  -         /dev/sg6
```

And use this to get the list of ports on your MB that correspond to the above devices:

```
$ lsscsi -H
[0]    ahci
[1]    ahci
[2]    ahci
[3]    ahci
[4]    pata_atiixp
[5]    pata_atiixp
[12]    usb-storage
```

You can also use the verbose output instead:

```
$ lsscsi --verbose
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDT72101 A3AA  /dev/sda
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0]
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDS72101 A39C  /dev/sdb
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0]
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Maxtor 6L200P0   1G20  /dev/sdc
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.1/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0]
[12:0:0:0]   disk    WD       My Passport 25E2 4005  /dev/sde
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/12:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0]
[12:0:0:1]   enclosu WD       SES Device       4005  -
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/12:0:0:1  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:1]
```

**NOTE:** The port that it's plugged into is the first digit in this block, `[0]` vs. `[4]` in the `lsscsi -H` output, for example.

#### lshw

I've also been able to use `lshw` for this because it tells you which ports etc. a particular HDD is plugged into so it's easier to figure out which one is which in a system that has multiples. Below you can see `/dev/sda` along with its serial number:

```
$ lshw -c disk -c storage
  *-storage
       description: SATA controller
       product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 11
       bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
       logical name: scsi0
       logical name: scsi2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
       resources: irq:22 ioport:c000(size=8) ioport:b000(size=4) ioport:a000(size=8) ioport:9000(size=4) ioport:8000(size=16) memory:fbbff800-fbbffbff
     *-disk:0
          description: ATA Disk
          product: Hitachi HDT72101
          vendor: Hitachi
          physical id: 0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: A3AA
          serial: STF604MH0AD4PB
          size: 931GiB (1TB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=0005edc1
```

You can figure out which is which based on the coordinates of their respective           bus info & physical id.

#### smartctl

The other method I've used in the past is `smartctl`. You can query each device independently to find out it's serial number, make & model and figure out which device it is once you open up the case.

```
$ smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 5.43 2016-09-28 r4347 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Deskstar 7K1000.B
Device Model:     Hitachi HDT721010SLA360
Serial Number:    STF604MH0AD4PB
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 349c4b953
Firmware Version: ST6OA3AA
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Thu Aug  2 21:11:01 2018 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

#### ledctl/ledmon

On higher end rackmounted servers you can use `ledctl` to light up the LED for a given HDD through its `/dev/` device name.

*ledctl usage*

```
# ledctl locate=/dev/rssda will blink drive LED
# ledctl locate={ /dev/rssda /dev/rssdb } will blink both drive LEDs
# ledctl locate_off=/dev/rssda will turn off the locate LED
```

#### References

- [Using ledmon/ledctl utilities on Linux to manage backplane LEDs for PCIE SSD Software RAID drives](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/3753.using-ledmonledctl-utilities-on-linux-to-manage-backplane-leds-for-pcie-ssd-software-raid-drives)
- [12 Storage Enclosure LED Utilities for MD Software RAIDs](https://susedoc.github.io/doc-sle/SLE12SP3/SLES-storage/html/cha.raid_leds.html#)

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure out which is which from this info. I find the using the drive's serial number is fool proof. With the `lshw` method, it seems I might also need to refer to the motherboard manual to know the ports ID's and then trace the cable from each drive to each port. Do you have a better way?

Comment: The ports are always labeled on the MBs.

Comment: `smartctl -i /dev/sdh | grep -i serial` should give you the serial number of the drive you're looking for.